# Comparing two txt files with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, text, compare

I have two files which are like following:
File1.txt

```
[2]    Baudÿ:            9600
[7]    Baudÿ:            9600
```

File2.txt

```
[1]COM1 
[2]COM2 
[3]COM22 
[4]COM56 
[5]COM57 
[6]COM58 
[7]COM59 
[8]COM60 
[9]COM27
```

I would like to compare those two files and have as output a third file like following:
File3.txt

```
[2]COM2 
[7]COM59
```

The code must be adapted for any line number in File1. May anyone please help me doing this? :)
Thanks

Comment: You can do this with a one-liner.  You don't need a script.  `for /f "usebackq" %I in ("file1.txt") do findstr /L "%I" "file2.txt">>"file3.txt"`  If you do want to put it into a .bat script, replace the single `%` with double.

Comment: Thanks for your help @rojo! The script didn't work the first time. I've just changed some parameters and it works!
Here's the final code:
`@echo off

for /f "usebackq delims=[]" %%I in ("File1.txt") do findstr /L "[%%I]" "File2.txt" echo>> "File3.txt"
`